# Cocoa NSPopupButton Problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, xib, nsviewcontroller

In my Cocoa Application, In One view i added a NSPopupButton via Interface builder and linked that accordingly with the source file, 
Now in the Code, i am creating Menu dynamically and adding menu with the NSPopupbutton,
This is i have done it in WindowDidLoad
Please refer the code below

```
 NSString *pThemeName;
 for(;index<count;index++)
 {
  pThemeName = [pThemeArray objectAtIndex:index];

  /* If its valid them go ahead and add that into the 
     list 

   */
  if([CommFileManager IsValidThemeName:pThemeName]){
   menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:pThemeName action:@selector(selectThemeName) keyEquivalent:@""];
   [menuItem setTarget:self];
   [pPopUpmenu addItem:menuItem];
   [menuItem setTag:index];
   [menuItem release];
  }
 }
 [pPopupButton setTarget:self];
 [pPopupButton setMenu:pPopUpmenu];
 [pPopupButton selectItem:[pPopUpmenu itemAtIndex:5]];
 [pPopUpmenu release];
```

When i run the application, then initially the button is Enabled, but when i click the arrow , including Menu and button gets disabled

Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: It looks fine to me, although you call `setTarget:` on the popup button without setting an action.  Since you're adding actions to each of the menu items, just leave the target/action of the button itself unspecified.

Comment: HI i tried without that also, no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an action for the NSPopUpButton to be enabled. Target is what's optional (as nil means first responder).

You do not need to set a target/action for the menu items, since the popup can tell you which item was selected when it calls its action against its target.